# How to clear jobs of only one worker in sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a worker like this:

```
class Worker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    # ...
  end
end
```

But there's something error with this worker, so I want to clear all jobs of it but don't want to clear jobs of other workers.

How can I implement this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the API to find and delete the jobs.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#queue

Comment: But the problem is there're too many jobs in that worker, about 3000,000. So the removing will be very slow. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Sidekiq Pro has Queue#delete_by_class(Worker) which is very fast as it's all performed within Redis in Lua.  Free or fast, take your pick.